# JQuery 'click' doesn't work on JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a little block of a code, and having difficulty with JSFiddle not initiating a 'click' function when I click on the links that are embedded into another element, but the function works when I just click on a stand-alone link.

Here's a link to JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrII/hwte6w27/16/

I'm talking about the "X" links that are built into the 'newdivs' after you run the javascript code at least once. And the JQuery ($('a') etc.) function doesn't seem to work on those in JSFiddle.

Any ideas why?

```
<a href="#">Test link</a>

<div>
    <form onsubmit="adDiv(); return false" method="post">
        <p> Counter: <span id="wow">0</span></p>
        <input id="texts" style="width:200px" type="text" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="test"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
function adDiv(){
var textVal = document.getElementById('texts').value;

if (!textVal){
    return false;
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
var tag = document.createElement("span");
var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById('wow').innerHTML);
var divid = counter+1+"div"; 

tag.title = "tag1";
tag.className = "tag1";
tag.href = "#";
tag.innerHTML = document.getElementById('texts').value;

div.className = "newdiv";
div.id = divid;    

document.body.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById(divid).appendChild(tag);

var tag2=document.createElement("a");
tag2.className="tag2";
tag2.innerHTML = "x";
tag2.href = "#";
tag2.id = "newtag";

document.getElementById(divid).appendChild(tag2);

document.getElementById('wow').innerHTML = counter + 1

document.getElementById('texts').value = "";}
```

---

### $( "a" ).click(function() {alert("testqwq3");});

```
.newdiv {
display:block;
width:200px;
height:auto;
background-color: #E0EAF1;
border-bottom: 1px solid #3E6D8E;
border-right: 1px solid #7F9FB6;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px gray;
color: #3E6D8E;
font-size: 90%;
line-height: 1.0;
margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
padding: 3px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;}    

.tag1 {
width:175px;
height:17px;
display:inline-block;
color:#3E6D8E;}    

.tag2 {
width:20px;
height:17px;
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin-right:2px;
text-align: right;
color:#C0CBCF;
text-decoration: none;}

.tag2:hover {
     color:#3E6D8E; }
```

Comment: try `$(document).on('click',"a",function(){ //Yor code })`

Comment: If you;re using jQuery, why are you doing things like `document.getElementById('texts').value` and `document.createElement("div")`. If you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery.

Comment: I started learning web development last week - still trying to grasp different concepts and libraries. But I will probably move towards JQuery more as I learn it better.

Comment: $(document).on('click',"a",function(){ //Yor code }) is giving me an error in JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
$( "a" ).click(function() {
    alert("testqwq3");
});
```

will find any `a` elements taht exist **when it runs** and add a click handler to them. Since the elements you add later aren't there when the code runs, naturally it doesn't hook up handlers on them.

You can either hook up a handler on your `tag2` elements as you add them in `adDiv`, or use event delegation. Here's what delegation looks like:

```
$("some container element").on("click", "a", function() {
    alert("testqwq3");
});
```

That hooks click on the container element, but only calls your handler if the click *passed through* something matching the given selector when bubbling to the container.

In your fiddle, there's no suitable container other than `document`, so: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwte6w27/17/)

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    alert("testqwq3");
});
```

...but in reality normally there's some appropriate container you'd hook a bit closer to the actual elements that will be added dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 1):

Because click event handler is not bind to newly created elements. Modify code to:

```
$( document ).on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert("testqwq3");
});
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: If the OP has an older version of jQuery, they might want `$.live()` instead.

Comment: This seems to work. I just wonder - why did $('a').click(function(){}; not work?

Comment: @Alze see T.J. Crowder's answer for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers provided details that code is not present at time of attaching events they have provided use of .on() as solution. you can also use delegate() for future handlers

```
$(document).delegate("click", "a", function() {
    alert("testqwq3");
});
```

here document can be replaced by any of the container selector

Comment: `on` superceded `delegate` more than three years ago, as of v1.7. But if you're going to show it, you'll want to get the argument order right (it's not the same as `on`'s, which you've used above).